# Log text value into a textarea in a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, encryption, cracking

Okay, so, just to clear this idea up, I couldn't crack a custom encryption code, and so I just tried to find a way to log all of the encryptions for the codes I want into a textarea and copy them. If that doesn't make sense, just tell me, I'll try to explain it in a more detailed way.

The encryption would work by taking what you typed in a textbox, encrypting it, and then submitting the form with the encryption. I'm attempting to take advantage of this by removing the submission, and using a for loop to enter a number into the textbox, calling the encryption function, then logging the encryption into a textarea. Heres the code:

```
        function encryption(form) {
        for (var i = 100; i < 1000; i = i + 1) {
            document.getElementById("fieldPassword").innerHTML =
            i
            doPCASLogin(form)
            var passwordinpforlist = document.getElementById("fieldPassword").innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("outputlistfordecryptions").innerHTML =
            passwordinpforlist
        }
    }
```

I'm not entirely sure what's wrong. Nothing will even log to the textarea. But, the encryption will still appear in the password text box like it's supposed to. The ID for the textbox is "fieldPassword". Yes, I checked that the ID for the textarea was "outputlistfordecryptions". And if you're wondering about doPCASLogin, it's the encrypting script. And it automatically changes the password field to the encryption.

If I'm missing something, please tell me. By the way, everything seems to work except for logging to the textarea. Maybe I incorrectly made the variable or something?

Comment: You don’t read from/write into input fields or textareas using .innerHTML, but using .value

Comment: @CBroe so should i change all lines with .innerHTML to .value?

Comment: @KingK Only if all lines using `.innerHTML` refer to an HTML `<input>` or `<textarea>` element.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you. Managed to get it working.

Comment: @Chiru Thank you. Managed to get it working.